# remove git username form git bash

Tags: git, bash, github

I tried to clone a repository from git bash using similar command to this command.

```
      git clone ssh://server.net/team/git/gui.git
```

then it asked the username and password. i entered wrong user name with password.
then later i tried to clone that repository using same command. but it is not asking for username. it just ask password for username@server.net(here username is the one i entered for username first time). so i can't clone that repo. how can i remove that user(username@server.net)?
thanks.

Comment: Do you have .gitconfig in $HOME directory?

Comment: yep. there is .git folder and .gitconfig file. thanks you. i got it worked.thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a user in the `clone` URL:

```
ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
```

Try cloning like so:

```
git clone ssh://correct_username@server.net/team/git/gui.git/
```

#### Reference:

- http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#_git_urls

Comment: Delighted to hear it.